# How can I fix this loose chandelier mount?

Tags: mount

This is the mount for a chandelier in our dining room.  I can tug downward on it and it's pretty solid.  There's still something holding it in place but when I push up it jiggles around.  It should be flush with the ceiling and not loose.

Is this something that someone with limited home improvement skills can fix?

[image]

**Update:**

So I took the faceplate off and unscrewed the mount and it was mounted to this bar about 18" long that's not secured to anything. It's just laying on the sheetrock. There are joists on either side, or plywood above, that I could mount the bar or something else to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect that there's a mounting bar across the top of the box, but the bar's come loose. Can you get a close-up with that cover removed? Can you see anything past the box?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  Added an update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With another floor above try removing the plate on the face of the box and see if there are some screws that are loose you can tighten, if no screws , push the box up is it hitting something? That will be a cross brace to screw into. The box is usually less than 2-1/2 deep and with a floor above there should be 6-12 “ clear above the box other than the brace, I have had nails come loose and used screws to reattach the boxes in many cases over the years. The box may also be attached on the side in that case shooting a screw or 2 into the joist would work.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an attic above that ceiling or another floor? That would really help to determine how involved the repair would be. If it's just an attic then grab a flashlight, some gloves and a dust mask and go check it out from above. Like Daniel Griscom said the cross bar seems to have become detached in some way or another. If there is another floor above then you'll most likely have to remove drywall to get at the problem.....and then you end up with a HUGE can of worms if you are not experienced with drywall finishing especially with a textured ceiling. Let us know what you find.

Comment: There's another floor above that ceiling so not easy to get to.